# How to make an SRT file into a dataset?

Tags: vba, excel, srt

Is it possible to turn an `SRT` file, which is used for subtitles in videos **into a dataset**?

When imported into Excel, the `SRT` file format looks like this:

```
1
00:00:03,000 --> 00:00:04,000
OVERLAPS PURE COINCIDENCE THAT

...
```

This pattern continues as time in the "video"/transcript goes on.  I'd like to format the `SRT` file this way:

```
number ; start ; end ; text

1 ; 00:00:03,000 ; 00:00:04,000 ; OVERLAPS PURE COINCIDENCE THAT
```

Comment: Or you run a regex on the file with a good text editor, to turn it into a .csv, or tab delimited file then open in Excel

Comment: The format of a SubRipText file looks like fixed width should work.  You could open Excel, go to the data tab, select open text file and then specify your file to open.  The import wizard will walk you through showing how the output will look with the selections you make.

Comment: Are you planning on importing multiple SRT's?  Reason I ask is, they can come in slightly different formats.  In fact, if your sample is *one record per line* like that, then it's non-standard.

Comment: ah ha , I see the problem... I fixed your formatting.  And I just happen to have something that should do the trick for you.

Comment: Just want to upvote this question because it's a really straightforward request to get SRT data into a spreadsheet. I wish the answers that were put in comments here were actual answers to the question with details. The one about using the import wizard seems especially promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VBA procedure below loads a standard `.srt` (SubRip Movie Subtitle File) from a local file and splits it into rows/columns on the active Excel worksheet.

### Import SRT subtitles from Local File:

```
Sub importSRTfromFile(fName As String)
'Loads SRT from local file and converts to columns in Active Worksheet

    Dim sIn As String, sOut As String, sArr() As String, x As Long

    'load file
    Open fName For Input As #1
        While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, sIn
            sOut = sOut & sIn & vbLf
        Wend
    Close #1

    'convert LFs to delimiters & split into array
    sOut = Replace(sOut, vbLf & vbLf, vbCr)
    sOut = Replace(Replace(sOut, vbLf, "|"), " --> ", "|")
    sArr = Split(sOut, vbCr)

    'check if activesheet is blank
    If ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        If MsgBox(UBound(sArr) & " rows found." & vbLf & vbLf & _
            "Okay to clear worksheet '" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'?", _
            vbOKCancel, "Delete Existing Data?") <> vbOK Then Exit Sub
        ActiveSheet.Cells.ClearContents
    End If

    'breakout into rows
    For x = 1 To UBound(sArr)
        Range("A" & x) = sArr(x)
    Next x

    'split into columns
    Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"

    MsgBox "Imported " & UBound(sArr) & " rows from:" & vbLf & fName

End Sub
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Sub test_FileImport()
    importSRTfromFile "c:\yourPath\yourFilename.srt"
End Sub
```

---

### Import SRT subtitles from Website URL:

Alternatively, you can import an `.srt` (or other similar text files) from a **Website** URL such as [https://subtitle-index.org/](http://subtitle-index.org/) with this:

```
Sub importSRTfromWeb(url As String)
'Loads SRT from URL and converts to columns in Active Worksheet

    Dim sIn As String, sOut As String, sArr() As String, rw As Long
    Dim httpData() As Byte, XMLHTTP As Object

    'load file from URL
    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    XMLHTTP.send
    httpData = XMLHTTP.responseBody
    Set XMLHTTP = Nothing
    sOut = StrConv(httpData, vbUnicode)

    'convert LFs to delimiters & split into array
    sOut = Replace(sOut, vbLf & vbLf, vbCr)
    sOut = Replace(Replace(sOut, vbLf, "|"), " --> ", "|")
    sArr = Split(sOut, vbCr)

    'check if activesheet is blank
    If ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        If MsgBox(UBound(sArr) & " rows found." & vbLf & vbLf & _
            "Okay to clear worksheet '" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'?", _
            vbOKCancel, "Delete Existing Data?") <> vbOK Then Exit Sub
        ActiveSheet.Cells.ClearContents
    End If

    'breakout into rows
    For rw = 1 To UBound(sArr)
        Range("A" & rw) = sArr(rw)
    Next rw

    'split into columns
    Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
    MsgBox "Imported " & UBound(sArr) & " rows from:" & vbLf & url

End Sub
```

### **Example Usage:**

```
Sub testImport()
    importSRTfromWeb _
        "https://subtitle-index.org/download/4670541854528212663953859964/SRT/Pulp+Fiction"
End Sub
```

Many sites host free `.srt`'s; you may have to right-click the download button to copy the link (which may have an `.srt` extension or might be a pointer, like the example above).  The procedure won't work on `.zip`'d files.

---

### More Information:

- Wikipedia : [SubRip & SRT](http://subrip/)
- MSDN : [Split Function (VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/split-function)
- Wikipedia : [Newline characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)
- MSDN : [UBound Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/ubound-function)
- MSDN : [Range.TextToColumns Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-texttocolumns-method-excel)
- [SubRip Official Website](http://zuggy.wz.cz/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there another website that is equivalent to subtitle-index.org as this seems to be down?

Answer (score 0):

in the above code :

`'breakout into rows
    For rw = 1 To UBound(sArr)
        Range("A" & rw) = sArr(rw)
    Next rw`

should be replaced with:

`'breakout into rows
    For rw = 0 To UBound(sArr)
        Range("A" & rw+1) = sArr(rw)
    Next rw`

else the output will start from line 2

Answer (score 0):

I used Vim and wrote a quick regex to convert a .srt into a .csv file for a translator friend who needed a similar conversion. The csv file can then be opened in Excel / LibreOffice and saved as .xls, .ods or whatever.
My friend didn't need the subtitle numbers to appear in the first column so the regex code looks like this :

```
set fileencoding=utf-8
%s/"/""/g
g/^\d\+$/d
%s@^\(.*\) --> \(.*\)\n@"\1","\2","@g
%s/\n^$/"/g
```

Variant to keep the sub numbering :

```
set fileencoding=utf-8
%s/"/""/g
%s@\(^\d\+\)$\n^\(.*\) --> \(.*\)\n@"\1","\2","\3","@g
%s/\n^$/"/g
```

Save this code into a text file with the `.vim` extension, then source this file when editing your .srt in Vim / Gvim. Save the result as a .csv. Enjoy the magic of Regexes !

NB : my code uses commas as field separators. Change the commas into semi-colons in the above code to use semi-colons. I've also added double-quotes as string delimitors in case double-quotes and commas occur in the subtitle text. Much more error proof !